# Что такое Critical rendering path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, терминология, оптимизация-сайтов

Объясните, пожалуйста, значение термина *Critical rendering path*.

Comment: где ты увидел этот термин и причем тут css?

Answer (score 10):

*Critical rendering path* — путь, который проходит браузер до того, как страница отрисовывается в браузере.

Этот путь в общем виде состоит из таких шагов (без детализации работы на сетевом уровне):

1. Получение ответа от сервера — HTML. Браузер парсит HTML, чтобы построить DOM
2. Построение объектной модели CSS — CSSOM.
3. Выполнение скриптов (поэтому, в основном, их надо помещать в конце документа).
4. Построение дерева рендера на основе DOM и CSSOM.
5. Отрисовка страницы.

Если рассматривать этот путь в разрезе CSS, то CSS является блокирующим рендер ресурсом, т. е. если во время разбора HTML браузер встречает ссылку на CSS-файл, то продвижение по пути останавливается и браузер начинает скачивать файл и разбирать его. Для оптимизации этого процесса рекомендуется помещать CSS, достаточный для отображения первого экрана, в `<head>` внутрь тега `<style>` — таким образом браузер получит и начнет парсить CSS по пути разбора всего HTML и не будет останавливаться на скачивание и разбор внешнего файла.

[Материал](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/?hl=ru) на developers.google.com.

Answer (score 3):

применительно к css - это стили влияющие на первую 1000 пикселей высоты страницы размещенные инлайн. это позволяет ускорить отображение страницы еще до загрузки полного css.