# Почему defer не работает?

Tags: javascript, html

Примитивный пример: Есть скрипт с алертом, подключенный вот так `<script src="js.js" defer></script>` с defer. При обновлении сперва появляется алерт и только потом контент страницы. Почему так ведь defer подразумевает сперва загружать содержимое страницы и только потом скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрипт с атрибутом `defer` выполняется не после отрисовки контента, а после окончания парсинга HTML, построения DOM и CSSOM. Ваш алёрт появляется потому, что к моменту его исполнения эти необходимые условия выполнены. Первый пэинт страницы происходит уже после.

`defer` нужен для того, чтобы не блокировать парсинг HTML и чтобы несколько идущих подряд скриптов выполнились в указанном порядке.

---

Вот вам пара статей на изучение: https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/, https://bitsofco.de/understanding-the-critical-rendering-path/

Comment: Ну да я же пёрфикт инглиш.. Получается, что страница уже загрузилась. А вот отрисовка блокируется.

Comment: ну, можно и так сказать, потому что между тем, как загрузился HTML и страница отрисовалась браузер проходит целый путь. вот тут я вкратце отвечал по этой теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636076/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-critical-rendering-path/636098#636098